# How can I bind to a view model in C# Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My C# code is like this now:

```
 stack.Children.Add(new FooterTemplate() { Text = Japanese.Helpers.Deck.SetIntro() });
```

but I would like to get the value of Text from my viewModel:

```
 vm.IntroFooter = Japanese.Helpers.Deck.SetIntro();
```

How can I bind the Text to vm.IntroFooter in C#

Comment: are you adding a FooterTemplate to a StackLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to bind a property in C#:

```
FooterTemplate ft = new FooterTemplate();
Binding binding = new Binding("IntroFooter");
ft.SetBinding(FooterTemplate.TextProperty, binding);
stack.Children.Add(ft);
```

I am assuming that you are properly using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
...
string _introFooter;
public string IntroFooter 
{
    get
    {
        return this._introFooter;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this._introFooter)
        {
            this._introFooter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```